# How to Save the search inputs and page number(state Save) of all of the tables in CoreUI data table

Tags: datatables, core-ui

[image]How to Save the search inputs and page number(**state Save**) of all of the tables in **CoreUI data table**
Eg. I search for a postcode, and go onto page 2. When I go back to the table after going onto the customers page, it should take me back to exactly where I left off, which is the search inputs and the page.
[image]
First Picture shows when I click on page No. 3 and move to another page or home page and then come back to customers it should return back to page No 3 not page No 1

Use Datatables as reference.
This is how it works on the CRM which uses Datatables JS plugin:
https://gyazo.com/13152d149f26792a87c9a8e38b0159ab

```
data: () => {
return {
  pageSizes: [10, 50, 100],
  items: store,
  fields: ['company_name', 'name', 'postal_code', 'phone1', 'phone2', 'email', 'created_at'],
  currentPage: 1,
  perPage: true,
  stateSave: true,
  totalRows: 0,
  you: null,
  message: '',
  showMessage: false,
  dismissSecs: 7,
  dismissCountDown: 0,
  showDismissibleAlert: false,
  customerModal: false
}
```

},

Comment: You have not shown us your DataTable definition, or what you have tried. Generally, state saving is managed by using the [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option. If that does not help, you can [edit] your question to show us a [mre].

Comment: I have updated my question, hope you will understand my point

Comment: Thank you for the updates - but unfortunately, these screenshots do not really provide any new information. I have the same comments as before: (1) You have not shown us your DataTable definition, or (2) what you have tried. (3) Did using the `stateSave` option not resolve your problem?  (4) Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: I have added the stateSave but unfortunately there is no detail mentioned of statesave in CoreUI Data Tables as I am Using CoreUI Data Tables

Comment: OK - understood. If the CoreUI data table is completely unrelated to DataTables (the jQuery plug-in) then you can remove the `datatables` tag from the question. Having said that, you may get some useful ideas from [this demo](http://live.datatables.net/neqozaj/1/edit). It shows how to use the [JavaScript state saving API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (but it is for DataTables - so you would have to adapt the approach to your CoreUI situation, of course).